# QGIS Desktop 2.9.0 - ZoomOut doesn't work

Tags: qgis

In the QGIS Desktop 2.9.0-Master the Tool "zoomOut" doesn't work. The "zoomOut" have the same operation of the "zoomIn".
This is a bug?
I don't know where I report this bug, because I know the 2.9.0 is the qgis-dev version.

Comment: Please report bugs at http://www2.qgis.org/en/site/getinvolved/development/index.html#bugs-features-and-issues

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it should be a bug report.

Comment: FYI - this bug was already fixed in 2.8.1 and 2.9 master. You probably just need to update your QGIS version.

Comment: It's stranger because I download the this using QGIS-OSGeo4W, and install I thought already the last version.
I'll download again. Thank you!